# Running a project consisting of a bunch of jl files in Julia

Tags: ubuntu, package, julia

I am new to Julia.

I have a collection of *.jl files. Some define certain modules:

> module AAA
> using BBB
> export aaa
> function fff(yyy)
> return zzz
> end
> end

some of these used BBB are modules defined in the other files in my collection.

One of these *.jl is certain master.jl, whose overall task is to read some input data and produce certain output; it uses modules defined in all my other *.jl's. I need to make it perform this task.

I have compiled julia from source with gcc on my Ubuntu 22.04 workstation; it is ver.1.11.0. As a result I have folder $HOME/julia with link to executable
julia -> usr/bin/julia

and folder
$HOME/.julia
with subfolders

```
logs
artifacts
packages
registries
config
prefs
compiled
conda
environments
scratchspaces
```

which were created automatically (apart from config; config was my experimenting based on the advice here on stackoverflow).

Now I am stuck how to run my collection of modules.

Invoking

> julia AAA.jl

from command line produces errors

ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package BBB not found in current path.

- Run `import Pkg; Pkg.add("BBB")` to install the BBB package

whenever AAA.jl uses a module BBB defined in BBB.jl. Even if I have run julia BBB.jl beforehand with no errors in the same window.

How do I organize my collection AAA.jl, BBB.jl, ... master.jl into a project so that all the modules defined in different files are properly included together?

Answer (score 2):

The error

```
ERROR: LoadError: ArgumentError: Package BBB not found in current path.
```

is because Julia doesn't know about BBB.jl when it's running AAA.jl or master.jl. Running `julia BBB.jl` in the same window previously doesn't create any relation between the two scripts, so doesn't change anything.

##### Fix 1: Using [include](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1//base/base/#Base.MainInclude.include) and [relative module qualifiers](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1//manual/modules/#Submodules-and-relative-paths)

In every file that uses a different module, `include` that other module's file, and use dot to access it. For eg. AAA.jl will become:

```
module AAA

include("BBB.jl")
using .BBB
export aaa
function fff(yyy)
  return zzz
end

end
```

This brings the contents of BBB.jl into AAA.jl, and makes `BBB` a submodule of `AAA` that can be accessed with the dot syntax as `using .BBB`. Note that this must be done in every file that uses another module, for eg. if master.jl needs to use `AAA` and `DDD`, its contents should be:

```
include("AAA.jl")
include("DDD.jl")

using .AAA
using .DDD
```

(If master.jl doesn't directly use `BBB`, then it doesn't need to be included. The `include` in AAA.jl is sufficient.)

##### Fix 2: Changing the package loading path

If only master.jl contains code you want to directly run, and the other files contain only modules you load from master.jl, an easier fix is to add

```
push!(LOAD_PATH, @__DIR__)
```

at the beginning of master.jl. In this case, you don't need the `include`s or the dot syntax, everything else in your files can stay as they are. `@__DIR__` refers to the directory that contains master.jl, and `push!`ing it into `LOAD_PATH` makes it so that Julia searches that directory when it comes across `using BBB` and can't find it anywhere else.

##### Side note

> I have compiled julia from source with gcc on my Ubuntu 22.04 workstation; it is ver.1.11.0.

You almost certainly don't want to do this if you're new to Julia. Julia version 1.11 is currently still under development, and is not yet considered stable - its release will likely be around mid-2024! The best way to install a stable Julia is to use the  [juliaup](https://github.com/JuliaLang/juliaup/) script, which will let you install and update current stable Julia (which is version 1.9.4 as of 23 Nov 2023). If for some reason you do want to compile from source, I'd recommend downloading https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/archive/refs/tags/v1.9.4.zip instead of the current `master` (which is probably what you've compiled into a v1.11 binary right now).